# SQL statements via php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i'd like to know if it's allowed, i mean it worked for me, but is it a good practice? if not, what issues i will be dealing with ahead... i'm a php/script virgin btw.

```
// button
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit-button" >Save changes</button>

<script>
$("#Submit-button").click(function() {
<?php 
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$result = $db_connection->query('update reservation set gm_submit="Y"');    
?>
});
</script>
```

-------UPDATE---------------

k.. here's what i did... and it worked fine...

```
$("#SaveButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'db.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {}
    });

});
```

i'm fine by this?

Comment: use ajax instead of js

Comment: No you should not use this. Instead you should make an ajax call to the php script that will do the same task for you...adding server side language to the client site language is a bad practice i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax post  and process the db updation.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'db.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {}
});
```

DB.php

```
<?php 
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$result = $db_connection->query('update reservation set gm_submit="Y"');   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work since PHP is a server side language and your binding your computation to a JS callback, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315582/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax/20315672#20315672) answer, it's a very similar problem.